# How to use gmail api's in chrome extension?

Tags: gmail-api

I am new to chrome extensions  and gmail api's.
I am trying to connect with gmail api's while implementation of my extension.
I have api keys and client id.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you first need to add :

```
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js" ,"client.js"]
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src https://*.google.com 'unsafe-eval';   object-src 'self'",
"oauth2": {
  "client_id": "<your client id>",
"scopes": [
        scope: 'https://mail.google.com/'
]
},

"permissions": [
    "background",
    "identity",
  "tabs",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/*",
    "https://*.googleusercontent.com/*",
"https://mail.google.com/",
  ],
```

When client.js is the gmail API library ...
Now in your background page you need to connect..I give you example in JS:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken(
{'interactive': true},
function(token){        
  /// you can use the token( user token ) for create http request to gmail api
}  
);

 window.gapi_onload = function(){
  gapi.client.setApiKey("<your api code>");

 gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
        client_id: '<Your client id>',
        immediate: true,
        scope:     "https://mail.google.com/",

    },
    function(){
      gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', gmailAPILoaded);
    }
   );


   }
   function gmailAPILoaded(){
            // Do things you want with  gapi.client
   }
```

Most of things I give you based on [this guide](http://developer.streak.com/2014/10/how-to-use-gmail-api-in-chrome-extension.html) but it's not work for me exectly so I change some things.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need the `gapi.auth.authorize(...)` calls. Look for the `chrome.identity` API instead.