# I am working with chrome extension using javascript. i need to communicate with gmail api. But iam getting error as login required

Tags: gmail-api

I am working with chrome extension using javascript. i need to communicate with `gmail api`. But iam getting error as login required

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it really give you the enough message, All requests to the Gmail API must be authorized by an authenticated user. Gmail uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authenticating a Google account and authorizing access to user data. You can also use Google+ Sign-in to provide a "sign-in with Google" authentication method for your app.

Here is the official document from google:
[Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth)

Here is a quick guide for you:
[How to use the Gmail API in a Chrome extension](http://developer.streak.com/2014/10/how-to-use-gmail-api-in-chrome-extension.html)

Actually I just google it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this header to your request:

```
    xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + userToken);
```

When you get userToken after you use the Oauth2.
look the guide that write for you in previous comment and in this [How to use gmail api's in chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118712/how-to-use-gmail-apis-in-chrome-extension/41121611#41121611) question to continue .

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Inside a Chrome extension, look for the chrome.identity API, which allows you to retrieve an OAuth2 access token for the Chrome user and the OAuth2 scopes as configured in your extension's manifest. Alternatively, that API provides a convenience wrapper for a 3rd party OAuth2 client authentication flow. You want to use that option whenever you do not want to invoke Google's APIs (such as the GMail API) on behalf of the Chrome user, but another Google account.